# how to fragment Method in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, permissions

I want permission visibility in MVVM pattern

my ViewModel code:

```
private val _permissionVisibility = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    val permissionVisibility: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _permissionVisibility

fun permissionDialog() {
        val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        val REQUEST_PERMISSION_LIST = 2222
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity!!, permissions, REQUEST_PERMISSION_LIST)
    }
```

my XML code:

```
android:visibility="@{ViewModel.permissionVisibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
app:onSafeClick="@{()-> ViewModel.permissionDialog()}"
```

what i want:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray)
```

call back in a fragment, not in an activity 
This callback value comes in as an activity

I don't know how to get it from the fragments here

could you help me please?

Comment: If you want the Fragment to get the callback, then don't use the Activity to call it, use the Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],%20int)) on the `Fragment` to get the callback to the Fragment's `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```
fun permissionDialog() {
    val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    val REQUEST_PERMISSION_LIST = 2222
    fragment!!.requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_PERMISSION_LIST)
}
```

As you should not hold onto any references to your Activity or Fragment in your ViewModel (as that would be a memory leak if you hold onto it after the Fragment is destroyed), this code should *really* be in your Fragment itself.

Comment: But the act of doing this is thought to be business logic, so isn't it right in the viewmodel?

Comment: You're breaking a much harder architecture layer problem by referencing your Activity/Fragment in your ViewModel at all. You could certainly have your ViewModel send a signal to your Fragment to run code, but at that point you're not really testing anything, but adding redirection for the sake of redirection, IMO.